# require.js is returning knockout, instead of required file

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui, requirejs, durandal

I'm using the kendoPanelBar [knockout-kendo bindings](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/PanelBar.html) and I'm having a problem with Durandals system.acquire method returning me the knockout object when I acquire a viewmodel.  This seems to only happen when I do the system.aquire from within the panels events.  If I run the same code from a click event outside of the panel everything seems to work fine.  Any ideas?

in the ParentViewModel:

```
this.stepExpand = function (e) {

            currentStep = ko.dataFor(e.item);
            if (currentStep.isLoaded() != true) {
                return system.acquire(currentStep.moduleId()).then(function (**module**) {
                    var module = new module(); <--getting the ko object here
                    module.activate();
                    currentStep.module(module);
                });
            }
       };
```

Parent view:

```
<ul data-bind="kendoPanelBar: { expandMode: 'single', widget: panel, expand: stepExpand, select: stepSelected}, foreach: steps">
<li data-bind="kendoPanelItem: {enabled: enabled}, visible: visible">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <div data-bind="compose: module"></div>
</li>
```

----Update----
[sample](http://pastelink.me/dl/5377be),
The sample calls require() directly since that's what Durandals system.acquire was doing internally.  Every once in while the sample will work correctly, if that happens just hit refresh and you will see the issue.  Click the first `<li>` in the list with the debugger open and you will see it returns knockout instead of the requested file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having here is the with the `compose` binding handler.  It has to be hooked to a view and model.  Without really seeing your real project code, my assumption is that the view and model are not lined up for the `compose` to find both.

Your example in the question and the example in the question are different.  The downloaded example, I got to resolve by doing two things:

1. Add `model.html` to the views folder:

   ```
   <div>
     <div>Model Details</div>
     <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Changed the `compose` binding in the `welcome.html` file:

   ```
   <div data-bind="compose: { model: module, view: 'views/model.html' }">
   ```

Also, take a look at [Using Composition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/) in the DurandalJS Documentation for other ideas how to handle the `compose`.

Comment: I've used compose plenty of times with only giving it a viewmodel parameter.  And if I set the module property when the page loads instead of in the expand event everything works.

Comment: What is your reason for the delay in loading the module property?

Comment: Performance issues, I don't want to load a module if the user is never going to go to it.  In my real project there could be > 15 modules all making service calls.